# Getting SQL Column to print in Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a code that prints out a specific column from an SQL query table. It prints out fine however I would like it to be put into a file and I cannot think of how to do that.

Here is what I have:

```
#Connect to the database
testDBCon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('xxx')

#Choose what query to select a column from
query = "SELECT * FROM testDB.dbo.PIESData;"

#Choose to print out all rows and columns Selected
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    df = pd.read_sql(query, testDBCon)

#Prints out only PartNumber and converts it to a string and prints all the values in every row
print( df[['PartNumber']].to_string() )
```

I was thinking of `newfile.write( df[['PartNumber']].to_string() )` however that did not work.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what type of file, pandas supports many formats For a simple csv file you can do:

```py
df.to_csv('file.csv', columns = ['PartNumber'], index = False)
```

Comment: it works however with each lien there is a count like 0,XXX 1,XXX... how would I get ride of this count (`78,X01CJ0030
79,X01CJ0031
80,X01CJ0032
81,X01CJ0034
82,X01CJ0035`)

Comment: try to use : index = False, i have edited the answer :)